# Kubernetes pod in Terminating state till worker up again

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm running a Kubernetes cluster with one node manager and 4 nodes workers.
when i start a pod , this one is correctly assigned to one worker and it start to run.
When i shutdown the worker where the pod was assigned, the manager detect the node NotReady after 40 seconds, and after 2 second the pod become Terminating.
i set this toleration for my pod:

```
spec:
  tolerations:
    - key: "node.kubernetes.io/unreachable"
      operator: "Exists"
      effect: "NoExecute"
      tolerationSeconds: 2
    - key: "node.kubernetes.io/not-ready"
      operator: "Exists"
      effect: "NoExecute"
      tolerationSeconds: 2
```

so the behavior is what i expected.
What i'm not expecting is that the pod remain in Terminating status till the worker come back to Ready.
When the worker is up again the pod is deleted from my system.
My expectation is once the tolerationSeconds expired the pod has to be scheduled on a different worker and run again.
Below the cluster with the versions:

```
docker1   Ready    <none>   21d   v1.17.4   192.168.1.2   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   5.5.9-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64    docker://19.3.8
docker2   Ready    <none>   21d   v1.17.4   192.168.1.3   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   5.5.11-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64   docker://19.3.8
docker3   Ready    <none>   21d   v1.17.4   192.168.1.4   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   5.6.4-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64    docker://19.3.8
docker4   Ready    <none>   19d   v1.17.4   192.168.1.5   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   5.6.4-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64    docker://19.3.8
manager   Ready    master   22d   v1.17.4   192.168.1.1   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   5.5.9-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64    docker://19.3.8
```

can anyone suggest me what i am missing or if this one is the correct behavior ?

Comment: Its your local env or cloud? Are you using VirtualBox or something similar? Could you provide logs from the pod which stuck on "terminating"? Also could you provide some steps to reproduce this behaviour? I assume you are using kubeadm. Did you try to remove those tolerations? Kubernetes have built-in mechanism that it will reschedule pod to `Ready` node in case other node will be unavailable.

Comment: Hi, i'm not using any sort on virtual environment, all servers are HP proliant. I already tried to remove the toleration and things gets even worst, after 40s he waits 300s more (default timeout). I create a pod without any volumeMounts or nodeSelector and manager assigned the pod to docker3. Then I simply shutdown (shutdown -r now) the docker3 server and wait. "kubectl get pod" said Terminating till docker3 up again then the pod disappeared. Unfortunately im in smart working today and I don't have access to the servers...ill try to edit my post with the yaml file of the pod.

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behavior. If instead of a desired shutdown you had for example a network issue, the pod may have kept running in the other node, when reconnecting it will have come back to running status, keeping any information and operations it may have been doing during that time.